# IE8 not support getElementsByClassName

Tags: internet-explorer-8, meta, getelementsbyclassname, x-ua-compatible

Since I make website with wordpress, which is the jquery affect part not show in IE7 and IE8, read the browser error, it show: object not support this method: 'getElementsByClassName', in this case i add follow code in header.php:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=9"/>
```

and to justify the browser version:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/wow.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]><script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/wow_ie8.js"></script><![endif]-->



 <!--[if !IE]><!--><script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/wow.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
```

And for js file part:
I just change

> wow.js

code to

> wow_ie8.js

from

```
this.boxes = this.element.getElementsByClassName(this.config.boxClass);
```

to this code:

```
 this.boxes = this.element.querySelectorAll(this.config.boxClass);
```

Somehow the website still show the error:  object not support this method: 'getElementsByClassName'

Is anyone could give me the solution to solve this problem?? thanks a lots!!